# Bypass html tags

Tags: html, tags

I have simple question. How to disable html tags on specific area? I tried `<pre.>`, but it still works with `<i.>` and others. I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Do you mean make the markup show up as text in an HTML page or do you want to remove them completely on the server side?

Comment: make the markup show
up as text in an HTML page.

Comment: I'm afraid at least I don't know what you mean. Can you please elaborate a bit more? Do you want the disabled tags to show in the page as text or do you want to hide them? What do you want to happen to their content?

Comment: disabled
tags to show in the page as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the only reliable way to do this is to change the `<` and `>` characters to their respective HTML entity codes:

```
&lt;a href="somewhere.html"&gt;A link&lt;/a&gt;
```

The above would render on the page as:

```
<a href="somewhere.html">A link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
<!--pre>
code here
</pre-->
```

In that way you turn anything into comment between the tags

Also in that same way if you like to disable the effect of a specific tag you can do that too

From that

```
<p>
    This must be <strong>strong</strong>
</p>
```

To that

```
<p>
    This must be <!--strong-->strong<!--/strong-->
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<code>
...
</code>
```